Change attributes (ForeColor/BackColor) of TabButtons in Multipage fmTabStyleButtons
I'm driving crazy to find if there is a way to change the attributes (forecolor/backcolor) of Tab-Buttons of a Multipage Control when styled ad fmTabStyleButtons to enchance visibility
I'm struggling there's none.
Anybody can help ?
tryed sever workarounds but no solution found

If bay Tab-Buttons you mean each page caption area, then such a MultiPage Page tab does not have such properties, so you cannot change their color. When I wanted better emphasizing the active page I placed green (low height) labels above each page name, matching their width with the length of the respective page caption and created a function to hide all the others, except the one of the active page. If programmatically I changed the page caption, I also adapted the respective label width accordingly. If not this meaning, it would be good to better define what you mean by such a term...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Multipage object has "style" property which could be set to "fmTabStyleButtons" instead of Tabs and il you click on the effect is the same of ToggleButtons. I do use labels programmatically moved but I'm searching for an elegant way to highlight selected page without code. So I thought that changing colours of buttons could be the answer

Then, you were wrong...
